# loop over 2 pandas DataFrames with sequential order

Tags: pandas, algorithm, numpy

Assume there are two DataFrames (1st one represents the transitional probabilities and 2nd one stores possible permutation sequences of 3 items: A, B, C). These 3 items have various replicates (A has 3, B has 2, and C has 2). Each item worth differently (A = 10, B = 5, C = 1). The goal is to compute total amount of each permutation sequence and append this amount information into 2nd DataFrame. **Here, amount = item value in col0 + sum of the item value * a corresponding transitional probability (e.g., A -> B is 0.4, But B -> A is 0.2)**

1st DataFrame (TP)

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations

probs = np.asarray([ [0.3,0.4,0.3],
                     [0.2,0.3,0.5],
                     [0.6,0.1,0.3]])

prob_df = pd.DataFrame(probs, index = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
prob_df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
prob_df


      A   B   C
A   0.3 0.4 0.3
B   0.2 0.3 0.5
C   0.6 0.1 0.3
```

2nd DataFrame

```
items = ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C']
perms = permutations(items)
output = [i for i in perms]
perm_df = pd.DataFrame(output).drop_duplicates()
print(perm_df.shape)
perm_df.head()

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   A   A   A   B   B   C   C
2   A   A   A   B   C   B   C
3   A   A   A   B   C   C   B
12  A   A   A   C   B   B   C
13  A   A   A   C   B   C   B
```

The amount of each permutation seq is calculated as follow:
for row0: (A, A, A, B, B, C, C)
the amount = 10 (col0) + 10 * 0.3 (col0->col1) + 10 * 0.3 (col1->col2) + 5 * 0.4 (col2->col3) + 5 * 0.3 (col3->col4) + 1 * 0.5 (col4->col5) + 1 * 0.3 (col5->col6) = 20.3

for row12: (A, A, A, C, B, B, C)
the amount = 10 + 10 * 0.3 + 10 * 0.3 + 1 * 0.3 + 5 * 0.1 + 5 * 0.3 + 1 * 0.5 = 18.8

any idea? many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)+[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)+[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to create a long DataFrame of source/target pairs, then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with the reshaped probabilities, reshape back with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), multiply by the mapped weights and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
weights = {'A': 10, 'B': 5, 'C': 1}

perm_df['out'] = (pd
  .concat({'source': perm_df.shift(axis=1),
           'target': perm_df}, axis=1)
  .stack()
  .merge(prob_df.stack().rename('prob'),
         left_on=['source', 'target'],
         right_index=True, how='left')
  .assign(value=lambda d: d['prob'].fillna(1)
                          .mul(d['target'].map(weights)))
  ['value'].unstack().sum(axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
      0  1  2  3  4  5  6   out
0     A  A  A  B  B  C  C  20.3
2     A  A  A  B  C  B  C  19.5
3     A  A  A  B  C  C  B  19.3
12    A  A  A  C  B  B  C  18.8
13    A  A  A  C  B  C  B  17.8
...  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..   ...
4216  C  C  A  B  B  A  A  15.8
4272  C  C  B  A  A  A  B  11.8
4273  C  C  B  A  A  B  A  10.8
4276  C  C  B  A  B  A  A  10.8
4290  C  C  B  B  A  A  A  11.3

[210 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: I just check another sequence (row #4272: C,C,B,A,A,A,B) = 1 + 1*0.3 + 5*0.1 + 10*0.2 + 10*0.3 +10*0.3 + 5*0.4 = 11.8, which is not the same with 17.2. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @DaCard maybe I misunderstood the weights. I compute it as `10*1 + 10*0.3 + 10*0.1 + 5*0.2 + 5*0.3 + 1*0.3 + 1*0.4` = `17.4`

Comment: OK, I just realized "Each item worth differently (A = 10, B = 5, C = 1)". Easy to fix, see update.

Comment: OMG!!! @mozway you are my hero!!!!!! SUPER AMAZING!!!